# Using sed to dispose of every character until a given sequence

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I am trying to use sed to transform the stream `9906884*n.6[2213]` into `9906884[2213]`. I am currently using `awk '{A=$1; print A $7}'` to get it to the stream I mentioned, but I am trying to used sed to turn `*n.6[2213]` into `[2213]`.

Is there a proper sed regex to say "grab everything before '\[[0-9]*\]'" That is, find "[" and any amount of numbers and then "]" again. If so I will simply use `sed 's/the_sed_regex//g'` to dispose of the first few characters in the previous `awk` statement.

Comment: Any comments as to why this question is marked for closing as off-topic would be greatly appreciated so I can form my questions better in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using BASH you can do:

```
s='*n.6[2213]'
echo "${s/*[/[}"
[2213]
```

Or using sed:

```
echo "$s" | sed 's/.*\[/[/'
[2213]
```

Comment: aha, so you just grab everything up to and including `[` and then replace it with `[`? Why does the first instance of `[` need an escape sequence but the second one does not?

Comment: Because `[` is a special character in regex, hence requires escaping. But replacement is just literal text hence `[` doesn't need escaping.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to obtain your desired output. For example:

```
$ echo "9906884*n.6[2213]" | awk -F'[\[*]' '{print $1 "[" $3}'
9906884[2213]
```

or

```
$ echo "9906884*n.6[2213]" | sed 's/\*[^[]*//'
9906884[2213]
```

Either of the two approaches remove the part between the `*` and the `[` from the input. In the awk version, the `[` is removed and replaced.